Finding the mid-band gain of an operational amplifier
I am studying for an exam. Been practicing on my professor's past exams and in this one I'm asked to find the transfer function and the mid-band gain. For calculating mid-band gain I'm assuming I must do small signal analysis the same way I would for a BJT or MOSFET

The amplifier has an open loop gain of \$A_{vol} = 74dB \approx 5011 \$ but I've been given no GBP so I'm assuming we're still in ideal conditions, therefor for the transfer function I use the virtual short circuit method. As for mid-band gain, this is where I'm confused. Small signal model of this opamp should be the following I think (please note that the following is how our professor wants us to solve these circuits. I have the method nailed down for BJTs and MOSFETs but not for opamps so I don't know if I'm approaching this the wrong way)

The way our professor taught us, we can remodel this to get make it easier to approach by changing the way the feedback resistor or impedance acts in the circuit. I think I can use Y parameters for this, so:
$$
\begin{cases}
I_1 = Y_{11}V_1 + Y_{12}V_2\\
I_2 = Y_{21}V_1 + Y_{22}V_2
\end{cases}\\
Y_{11} = Y_{12} = Y_{21} = Y_{22} = \frac{1}{R
}$$
These Y parameters all have the same value, but \$Y_{12} \$ should be the feedback factor. This is how I remodeled the circuit (I've been told that \$Y_{21} \$ is negligible, although I'm not quite sure why):

current source can be replaced with an open circuit:

The gain for this type of feedback should be \$ A = \frac{V_o}{I_s} \$.
Knowing that \$V_{in}\$ is the voltage drop across \$R\$ in the input mesh, the expression should be
$$
V_{in} = -RI_s
$$
and knowing that \$V_o = A_{vol}V_{in}\$, plugging the expression I just found into this I get:
$$
\frac{V_o}{I_s} = A_{vol}R = A
$$
Plugging this into the normal feedback formula \$\frac{A}{1+\beta A} \$ I end up with the gain I'm looking for, however it's not in \$V/V\$ but \$V/A\$ so to calculate the one I need I do this:
$$
Av = \frac{A}{1+\beta A}\bigg(\frac{I_s}{V_s}\bigg)
$$
Given that \$V_s = (R + R_{sig})I_s \$
$$
\frac{I_s}{V_s} = \frac{I_s}{(R + R_{sig})I_s} = \frac{1}{R + R_{sig}}\\
A_v\bigg[\frac{V}{V}\bigg] =\frac{V_o}{I_s} \frac{I_s}{V_s} = \frac{A}{(1+ \beta A)(R + R_{sig})}
$$
I really don't know if the way I approached the problem is correct so I'm sorry if this is entirely wrong. I'd like to know where I made a mistake and why (I'm assuming there's probably an algebraic mistake in there, I did this on a rush), thank you for your help!

Did you ask this question before and recently? I'll give the same sort of comment I did back then; what do you mean by mid-band gain. I say this because there is no flat region in the response (that might be described as mid-band) that is at all clear.
